# Safari calculates wrong top position with position sticky in table when there are multiple tbodies

Tags: html, css, html-table, safari, sticky

I have a table that is grouped with multiple `<tbody>` elements, each one having one initial row with a `<th>` element that titles the group. I wan't these `<th>`:s to be sticky but I can't get safari to set the correct top position.

If I set `top: 0px` or any positive value on the `<th>`:s it works as expected in Firefox, Chrome and Edge but in safari I get 0px + the height of all above tbodies and caption. This results in all `<th>`:s getting stuck at the same time well below the top scroll position.

I can work around the problem by flattening the table, removing the `<tbody>` elements and putting all `<tr>`:s directly under the table. But that would complicate styling and it makes sense for accessibility to group the table in my case so I'd prefer if I didn't have to do that.

Do you have any ideas how can fix or work around this problem?

Expected (Chrome, Safari and Edge):

[image: Works in Chrome, Safari and Edge]

Safari 12:

[image: Doesn't work in Safari 12]

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
}

tbody th {
  top: 20px;
}

td {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <caption>The table</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First col</th>
        <th>Second col</th>
        <th>Third col</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Group 1</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>baz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>baz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>baz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>baz</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Group 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>baz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>baz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>baz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>baz</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Group 3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>baz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>baz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>baz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>baz</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I have the same issue with `th` in the first `thead` in the table. I want my `caption` and `th` to be sticky when the table is scrolled. I have given `th` `top: 46px` which is the height of `caption`. It works in chrome but not in safari.

Answer (score 2):

The code below will work for both Safari and Google Chrome. The trick is to change your `th`'s to `thead`'s and then set the position to sticky in various ways. `position: -webkit-ms-sticky`, `position: -webkit-o-sticky`, `position: -webkit-sticky`, `position:sticky`.

You should also add two check in css for the `thead` and in the second check find every child of that `thead` tag to ensure it selects each child tag in Chrome as well.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

tbody thead {
  top: 20px;
}

thead {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -webkit-o-sticky;
  position: -webkit-ms-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  background: white;
}

thead tr:nth-child(1) th{
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

td {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
      <table>
        <caption>The table</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First col</th>
            <th>Second col</th>
            <th>Third col</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="3">Group 1</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>baz</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>baz</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>baz</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>baz</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="3">Group 2</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>baz</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>baz</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>baz</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>baz</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="3">Group 3</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>baz</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>baz</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>baz</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>baz</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Hello!

Thank you for taking the time! It does indeed work, however according to the table spec the `<thead>` should be a child directly under the `<table>` and it should be followed by a any number of `<tbody>`:s. I noticed in your example that safari actually moves the nested `<thead>`:s up to the parent element. Doing that could maybe be the solution but the spec also say that there should only be on `<thead>` per table. Of course code that doesn't follow the spec precisely usually work so maybe this isn't a problem.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead

Comment: This doesn't work. I just run your snippet in Safari and it didn't work at all...